# Is it possible that the interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(x-a)^{n-1}$ bigger than $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

Given a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n$ with convergence radius $0<R<\infty$. Then we know that its derivative $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(x-a)^{n-1}$ also has the same convergence radius $R$. Then is it possible that the interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(x-a)^{n-1}$ strictly bigger than the original one? (Namely, additionally convergent at the endpoints which the original one diverges at.) I have the exactly converse example, but don't have this one.

Comment: I think you meant $n c_n(x-a)^{n-1}$ in your third sentence.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Yeah, you're right. My typo. Now edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $$S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nc_n(x-a)^{n-1}$$ exists for a given $x$. Then, define $a_n = nc_n(x-a)^{n-1}$ and $b_n = \frac{x-a}{n}$. Note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = S$ and that $\{b_n\}$ is monotone and bounded. Therefore, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nb_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(x-a)^n$$ converges by Abel's test. This implies that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nc_n(x-a)^{n-1}$ exists for a certain $x$, then so does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(x-a)^n$, so the interval of convergence of the series for the derivative cannot be larger than interval of convergence of the series for the original function.

Comment: I see. Thanks! By the way, why is this fact rarely mentioned in analysis books? I think it is substantial for beginners to clarify their concept about power series. ;)